# does object particle hair with collision kills emitter particle?

Tags: particles, collision

for example i have a plane, with trees on it, and i put the rain emitter particle and set it to die on hit on the ground object. does the particle from the ground(trees) will kill the emitter particle?
i wouldve test it myself(i did actually), but its very laggy for me to fully see.
but i could see the rain particle is just.. less. not sure if its the lagging, or the tree is actually killing the particle
if the tree does kills the particle, anyway i can disable it?

i have a lot of trees consisting of a single plane, there will be rain, i dont want the tree to kill the rain particle, only the ground itself. my question is will the tree kills the rain particle if it touches the tree[image]

Comment: Each Object that is has a Collision modifier has a check-box option to "Kill Particles" that collide with it.   Try an experiment with a simple test file that only has a PS object and a Collision objects, so that you can see this clearly and with little compute power.

Comment: Ah a picture is always worth a thousand words!  You have your trees formed by a Hair PS.  The blender physics are not good at cross-interaction, so that any Fluid physics will not interact with Hair, even if the tree object were defined as a Fluid Effector Collision object.

Comment: ohh okay, i guess i gotta up the amount of rain, they probably falling behind the tree, maybe the reason it seems less. thanks man

Comment: You may be stretching the limit of your machine if this plane of trees is very large